# How do check byte() is null in IIF condition in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have a column value in Hash format in db and column datatype is varbinary(8000).I convert it into byte array.

Problem is some time this column value has null value,now in my code I want to check if column value has null value then return default value of byte array,otherwise return column value using following code

```
 objUser.Password_Hash = IIf(reader("Password_Hash") Is Nothing, {}, reader("Password_Hash"))
```

this gives error as below

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Byte[]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `IIf` in VB unless you're using a version so old that that the `If` operator doesn't exist.  I think that that would mean VB 2005.

Secondly, a NULL value from a database is not `Nothing` in VB.  It is actually an object, specifically an instance of the `DBNull` class, represented by the `DBNull.Value` field.

Thirdly, while you can compare directly to `DBNull.Value` if required, data readers and `DataRows` actually have methods dedicated specifically to testing for NULL.

So, putting it all together:

```
objUser.Password_Hash = If(reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Password_Hash")),
                           New Byte() {},
                           DirectCast(reader("Password_Hash"), Byte()))
```